# Changing the background color of SVG element from CSS

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a centered SVG element in the HTML body, I try to change the displayed background color of the SVG element, although when I define a background color for the SVG the full window of the browser gets that color.

I am using this CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: black;
}

svg {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color:red;
}
```

The SVG is generated dynamically, so a priori I don't know the size of the SVG, that is why I am using `height:100vh`.

I can't modify the SVG.

a work around was `fit-content`

```
svg {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color:red;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

although with `fit-content` the result was different in every browser, I got different behaviors in Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

How can I change the background color of SVG element without change the background color of the rest of the window?

thanks in advance.

Comment: why defining a height? let the default one be used

Comment: @TemaniAfif If I don't define the `height` nothing is displayed

Comment: so your SVG doesn't have any intrinsic dimension and you have to explicitly define a size (no need to use 100vh). But we need to see the structure of the SVG you are using to give you accurate answers

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS `fill` property.

```css
svg {
  height: 100vh;
  fill: red;
  }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M21,21H3L12,3Z"/></svg>
```

Comment: If your intention is not to color the SVG itself but actually the background and want it limited to the size of the SVG, you'll have to get creative with a "wrapper" container and most likely `clip-path`